# How to call arbitrary deep python object?

Tags: python

I'm working on a script using an API from a software I use. I lack documentation for the methods available so I have little control over what I have. I'm looking to call a variable that can be buried arbitrarily deep in an object. I know the depth before hand but it can range widely.

Example:

```
index = ['foo','bar']
object['foo']['bar'].method()
```

I've tried something like:

```
temp = object[index[0]]
for ind in index[1:]:
    temp = temp[ind]
temp.method()
```

But this *makes a copy* (it does not according to the replies I've gotten) of the object and does not apply the method correctly. Index can be arbitrarily long.

My only working solution is to hardcode this by using:

```
if lengthIndex == 1:
    object[index[0]].method()
if lengthIndex == 2:
    object[index[0]][index[1]].method()
if lengthIndex == 3:
    object[index[0]][index[1]][index[2]].method()
# and so on ...
```

What is the proper way to code this?

Comment: Uh, no that doesn't make a copy?

Comment: Well at least when I tried this it did not apply the .delete() method. I'll try again to see if something else was wrong.

Comment: What is this `delete()` method you speak of? If you're talking about the finalizer `__del__()`, that's to be expected. Though I'm not clear on how you got from that to concluding that objects are being copied...

Comment: @Michele87 if you're thinking that Python is leaking because it's not finalizing everything your old `temp`'s, it's because there isn't anything old, you're just changing what (sub-) object `temp` is referring to.

Comment: Note that `__del__` is *never* immediately reliable, it is *really* easy for references to appear temporarily in all sorts of places (exceptions, non-CPython interpreters like PyPy, ...). Although you should use a function to help the *visible* reference disappear.

Comment: Use a `with` statement if you want reliable management of resources.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code sample doesn't copy the object. In Python, variables are references (at least that's how it *effectively* works), and when you assign something to a variable, you're just copying a memory address, not copying the thing itself. So if your only reason not to use that was that you wanted to avoid making unnecessary copies of objects, you have nothing to worry about.

What you do in your code sample is the way I would handle repeated indexing.

Comment: If you want to get technical, they're *names*, not variables. Names point at objects, and some objects can change (mutable), some can't (immutable).

Comment: Your right, it's not a copy. Maybe it was something else that when wrong, I will try again tomorrow when I have access.

Comment: @NickT Indeed, though I expressly did not want to get technical in this answer.

Comment: I just found out that the operator used is del object['foo']['bar'], which is probably not a great approach but it's what is being used (I'm translating operations done in GUI to a script to automate things). I guess what happens in that case is that the reference 'temp' is being deleted from the namespace but the original remains.

Comment: @Michele87 I guess you could say that... but it's a little odd to speak of references being deleted in Python. After all, the only thing that's being deleted is the association between the name `temp` and the object it referred to, but the object is still there, and the name `temp` is still there, it just refers to something else. In C-like terms, it's like doing a pointer assignment: `foo* temp = object->get(index[0]); temp = temp->get(index[1]);` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the main point of the question is asking for a function to index arbitrarily nested dictionaries then see the following:

```
def f():
    print('nested func')

def g():
    print('nested func 2')

def nested_value(nested_dict, keys):
    for k in keys:
        nested_dict = nested_dict[k]
    return nested_dict


nested_dict = {
    'foo': {
        'bar': {
            'baz': f
        },
        'taco': g
    }
}

keys = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
val = nested_value(nested_dict, keys)
val()

keys = ['foo', 'taco']
val = nested_value(nested_dict, keys)
val()
```

Output:

```
nested func
nested func 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [5]: def get_deep_object(obj, index):
   ...:     for i in index:
   ...:         obj = obj[i]
   ...:     return obj
   ...: 

In [6]: l = ["foo", "bar"]

In [7]: get_deep_object(l, [1])
Out[7]: 'bar'

In [8]: get_deep_object(l, [1,1])
Out[8]: 'a'

In [9]: get_deep_object(l, [1,1]).capitalize()
Out[9]: 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a shorter (but not necessarily more readable) solution via functional programming:

```
from operator import getitem
from functools import reduce

reduce(getitem, index, object).method()
```

`getitem` from `operator` is equivalent to `lambda data, key: data[key]`.